# Calculate $P(|X-Y| \leq 0.25)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

How do I calculate $P(|X-Y| \leq 0.25)$ where $X,Y \sim U([0,1])$?

I figured out that if $X \in [0,0.25]$, then $P(Y \leq X+0.5) = X+0.25$, if $X \in [0.25, 0.5]$, then $P(|X-Y| \leq 0.25 \ | \ X \in [0.25,5]) = 0.5$ and $P(|X-Y| \leq 0.25 \ | \ X \in [0.5,1]) = 1.25-X$.

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Draw a picture of the unit square on the $XY$ plane, and find the area of the points with this property.

Comment: You'll get a strip around the diagonal, and you can get the are by subtracting the are of two triangles from the square.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, I know how to do it graphically. But I am trying to do it using integration.

Comment: In this case, trying to do it by integration is fine, but to correctly determine the bounds of integration you need to consider the area being integrated which is still most easily done through looking at the graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question it seems that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so the joint density function is $f(x,y) = f_X(x) f_Y(y) = 1 \times 1 =1$.
Now $|X-Y| < 0.25 \Rightarrow -0.25 < Y-X < 0.25 \Rightarrow X-0.25 < Y < X+ 0.25$. But note from your graphical picture that when $ X\in [0,0.25]$ then $0  <Y < X+0.25$ and similarly, when $X\in [0.75,1]$ then $X-0.25<Y<1$ (Since for negative $y$ or $y$ bigger than 1, $f_Y(y) = 0$ and we can ignore them).
Now

$$
\begin{align}
P(|X-Y| < 0.25) & = \int_0^1 \int_{x - 0.25}^{x + 0.25} f(x,y) dy dx\\
& = \int_0^{0.25} \int_{0}^{x + 0.25} dy dx
+\int_{0.25}^{0.75} \int_{x-0.25}^{x + 0.25} dy dx
+\int_{0.75}^1 \int_{x-0.25}^{1} dy dx\\
& = 7/16
\end{align}
$$